# using hping2 to validate jumbo frames

Tags: networking, tcp, mtu, hping

I was wondering if anybody had used hping2/3 to validate jumbo frames.

I know for example you can do:

```
* ping -M do -s 8972 [destinationIP]
```

to do this task using ping, but I don't want to use ICMP to check this, since ICMP is blocked by some environments and datacenters, whereas TCP/IP is ubiquitous.

Does anybody know the equivalent hping2/3 command and how it would work?

thanks much

Comment: ICMP is an integral part of IP, so as ubiquitous as IP is, so is ICMP. From [RFC 792, INTERNET CONTROL MESSAGE PROTOCOL](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc792): "_ICMP, uses the basic support of IP as if it were a higher level protocol, however, ICMP is actually an integral part of IP, and must be implemented by every IP module._" Do you mean TCP or UDP rather than TCP/IP?

Comment: tcp I think..  udp is blocked at lots of places as well.